# MVC CORE RedirectToAction() not calling action

Tags: model-view-controller

I have a RedirectToAction statement which is not finding the named action.  It will find the Index method in the BundleNodes controller but not the PostNodes method.  Where am I going wrong?

```html
return RedirectToAction("PostNodes", "BundleNodes", new { id = bndl_id });
```

```html
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostNodes(BundleNode bidnid, int id)
{
  var result = _context.Nodes.Where(r => r.Name == id).ToList();
  foreach(var item in result )
    {
      Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
    }
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```

Comment: Looks like you are missing a route parameter for "bidnid"

Answer (score 0):

Seems like the only reliable way to access a Post method in a Controller is to use a `<Form></Form>` or at least that's the only way I have been able to make it work.  Just make sure to reference the controller and the action method.

Answer (score 0):

Consider changing `Task<IActionResult> PostNodes(int bidnid, int id)`

To : `Task<IActionResult> PostNodes(int bidnid, int id)`

Or: `Task<IActionResult> PostNodes([FromBody]BundleNode bidnid, int id)`

When using objects in the action names, you must ensure the model (BundleNode) is passed in the http request or it will not bind to your variable.

Redirect:

```
return RedirectToAction("PostNodes", "BundleNodes", new { bidnid = 1234, id = bndl_id });
```

Controller:

```
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public async Task<IActionResult> PostNodes(int bidnid, int id)
{
  var result = _context.Nodes.Where(r => r.Name == id).ToList();
  foreach(var item in result )
    {
      Console.WriteLine(item.Id);
    }
  await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
  return RedirectToAction(nameof(Index));
}
```